# How do I auto populate fields in Django Threadedcomments based on user.is_authenticated

Tags: django

It seems simple to me. If a user is authenticated, auto populate the relavent form fields and don't show them. If a user isn't authenticated, show the form fields. I've been looking everywhere and I can't seem to find the answer. Does anyone know of some way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your template you could do something like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}" />
</form>
{% else %}
<!-- use your "regular" form here -->
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: heres a great post with template tweaks: http://www.netboy.pl/2011/10/customizing-django-comments-for-registered-users/

Comment: Yes this works technically. But I was hoping to do it without having to alter the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This example come from real system, I've worked on. Hope that helps you out.

```
import datetime

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
import django.contrib.comments.forms
from current_user.middleware import get_current_user

class AuthCommentForm(django.contrib.comments.forms.CommentForm):
    def get_comment_create_data(self):
        """
        Returns the dict of data to be used to create a comment. Subclasses in
        custom comment apps that override get_comment_model can override this
        method to add extra fields onto a custom comment model.
        """
        return dict(
                content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.target_object),
                object_pk=force_unicode(self.target_object._get_pk_val()),
                user_name=get_current_user().username,
                user_email=get_current_user().email,
                user_url='',
                comment=self.cleaned_data["comment"],
                submit_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                site_id=settings.SITE_ID,
                is_public=True,
                is_removed=False,
                )

AuthCommentForm.base_fields.pop('url')
AuthCommentForm.base_fields.pop('name')
AuthCommentForm.base_fields.pop('email')
AuthCommentForm.base_fields.pop('honeypot')
AuthCommentForm.base_fields['comment'].label = False
```

Comment: I wish I could do two answers, because these both work. This is probably the approach that I'll take going forward.